# how to match username and their profile links and how to show the fetched data in table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, react-native

hope you all are safe. here im stuck in a problem.here i fetched users and their profile links from the site drupal.org using RegEx. but i got another links also.i want to fetch their profile links only and match the users and their profile links and show data in table is it possible in React js? currently it look like this

[image]

**i want the data look like this :**

[image]

please help me, thank you.. here is my git repo  https://gitlab.com/darshankoli2397/react-practice.git

```
import React,{ Component } from "react"

import Axios from "axios"

class UserList extends Component {
    constructor(prop) {
        super(prop);
        this.onChangeUserName = this.onChangeUserName.bind(this);

        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

        this.state = { users: null, profile:"", name:"" }
    }

    onChangeUserName(e) {
      this.setState({ name: e.target.value })
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    const userObject = {
        name: this.state.name,

    };
    Axios.get(`https://www.drupal.org/search/user/${this.state.name}`).then(
      response => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
              // all is good
              console.log('all is good');
              console.log(response);
              var olList = response.data.match(/(?<=\<ol class="search-results user-results"\>\s+).*?(?=\s+\<\/ol)/gs);
              
              var links = response.data.match(
                /(\b(https?):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gi

              );
              //preg_match_all('|https?://(?:www\.)?twitter.com/#!/[a-z0-9_]+|im', $text, $matched)
              
              this.setState({ users: olList });
              this.setState({ profile: links });
            } else {
                console.log('something is wrong');
                // something is wrong
            }
        }
    );

  }
   
    render() {
        return ( <React.Fragment>

          <h1 > Search Here users of Drupal < /h1> 
           <form align = "center" onSubmit = { this.onSubmit } >
            <input type = "search" name = "name" onChange = { this.onChangeUserName } placeholder = "Search" required / >
            <button type = "submit" > Search < /button >   
            </form >

          <h3>Relevent Search Results For Your Keywords : </h3>
            
              <table border="2" height="100" width="300">
                  <tr>
                    <td align="center"><h2>Username</h2></td> 
                    <td><h2>Profile Links</h2></td> 

                  </tr>

                  <tr>
            
                      <td dangerouslySetInnerHTML = { 
                          { __html: this.state.users }
                            } />

                      <td align="char" dangerouslySetInnerHTML = {
                          { __html: this.state.profile }
                          
                        } />
                  </tr>
              </table>
                 
        </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default UserList;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the users as anchors, to be sure that every user has it's own link:

Example: `<a href="https://www.drupal.org/user/4088">asdf</a>`

```
let userAnchors = response.data.match(/\<a href="(https?):\/\/www.drupal.org\/user\/\w*">[\w\s]*\<\/a\>/gi)
```

I found this 2 regex only that you can use to extract the name an url:

```
const nameExtractorRegex = /<a[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/a>/g
const linkExtractorRegex = /href="(.*?)"/g
```

The only thing remained is to parse the anchors

```
const users = userAnchors.map(anchor => {
    return {
        name: nameExtractorRegex(anchor)[1],
        link: linkExtractorRegex(anchor)[1]
    }
})
```

Hope it helped!